# Tailwind CSS not formatting

Tags: php, css, laravel, npm

So I'm new to Tailwind, I'm using Laravel with Tailwind. Followed all the docs. I have done the the NPM and includes in my webpack but my (Chrome) shows like this, not sure what I have done wrong? It's not picking up the styles (see screenshots). Seems like its pulling in some styles but not the others.

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiZmg.png)
[how supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBHi.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://tickets.local/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div>

<div>
    <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Ticket Details</h3>
</div>
<div class="mt-5 border-t border-gray-200">
    <dl class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <div class="py-4 sm:py-5 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Title</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 flex text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <span class="flex-grow"></span>
                <span class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0">
          <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
        </span>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4 sm:grid sm:py-5 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Details</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 flex text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <span class="flex-grow">Backend Developer</span>
                <span class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0">
          <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
        </span>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4 sm:grid sm:py-5 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Email address</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 flex text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <span class="flex-grow">margotfoster@example.com</span>
                <span class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0">
          <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
        </span>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4 sm:grid sm:py-5 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Salary expectation</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 flex text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <span class="flex-grow"> $120,000</span>
                <span class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0">
          <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
        </span>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4 sm:grid sm:py-5 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Details</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 flex text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <span class="flex-grow"> Fugiat ipsum ipsum deserunt culpa aute sint do nostrud anim incididunt cillum culpa consequat. Excepteur qui ipsum aliquip consequat sint. Sit id mollit nulla mollit nostrud in ea officia proident. Irure nostrud pariatur mollit ad adipisicing reprehenderit deserunt qui eu. </span>
                <span class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0">
          <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
        </span>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="py-4 sm:grid sm:py-5 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4">
            <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">Attachments</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-2">
                <ul role="list" class="border border-gray-200 rounded-md divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <li class="pl-3 pr-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between text-sm">
                        <div class="w-0 flex-1 flex items-center">
                            <!-- Heroicon name: solid/paper-clip -->
                            <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a3 3 0 00-3 3v4a5 5 0 0010 0V7a1 1 0 112 0v4a7 7 0 11-14 0V7a5 5 0 0110 0v4a3 3 0 11-6 0V7a1 1 0 012 0v4a1 1 0 102 0V7a3 3 0 00-3-3z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span class="ml-2 flex-1 w-0 truncate"> resume_back_end_developer.pdf </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0 flex space-x-4">
                            <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
                            <span class="text-gray-300" aria-hidden="true">|</span>
                            <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pl-3 pr-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between text-sm">
                        <div class="w-0 flex-1 flex items-center">
                            <!-- Heroicon name: solid/paper-clip -->
                            <svg class="flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a3 3 0 00-3 3v4a5 5 0 0010 0V7a1 1 0 112 0v4a7 7 0 11-14 0V7a5 5 0 0110 0v4a3 3 0 11-6 0V7a1 1 0 012 0v4a1 1 0 102 0V7a3 3 0 00-3-3z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span class="ml-2 flex-1 w-0 truncate"> coverletter_back_end_developer.pdf </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-4 flex-shrink-0 flex space-x-4">
                            <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Update</button>
                            <span class="text-gray-300" aria-hidden="true">|</span>
                            <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </div>
    </dl>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check the content of the css file `app.css`, and confirm the file is present and has Tailwind utility classes ?

Comment: i assume you are testing on local server and using vscode. you have to run frontend server also using the command "npm run dev"

Comment: Yes the utility classes are included

Comment: Thanks for the reply bob, using phpstorm and ran all the commands such as npm dev etc, just wondered if my divs were wrong

Comment: Does your browser console show any error messages? Like files not being loaded?

Comment: @whitespace no nothing on console

Comment: And the network tab confirms that the CSS is being loaded? Is it delivered with the correct `content-type` `text/css`?

Comment: webkit-backdrop is blank, maybe the error? and .backdrop